# Is using Red Hat 7.7 over 8.1 advisable for a project being developed right now?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, development

We are finishing our development cycle, for which our OS is RHEL 7.6.
The System Engineering team wants to use RHEL 7.7 for the next dev cycle, instead of using RHEL 8.1. The belief is that we don't have the resources to absorb 8.1 at this time.

Has anyone started developing on 8.1 yet?

My task is to determine the downside of using 7.7 now and 8.3 on our next cycle.

Note: Our Dev Cycle is 9-10 months and our life-time is about 2 years. Using 7.7 now gives us another 9 months to determine the impacts of 8.3, and forces us to use 7.7 for about 3 years.

- Is this a realistic approach?
- Any down-side to 7.7?
- Has anyone experienced issues migrating to RHEL 8?

Happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Which release will be the next LTS Redhat will release?

Comment: Voting to close since this is too broad and too opinion-based without knowing specifics. What kind of software are you developing? In what language and such? The reality is using one version over the other might have major impacts in something like Java but have no impacts in PHP, Python or Node.js.

Comment: "Has anyone started developing on 8.1 yet?" - This question is out of scope.  "Is this a realistic approach?" - Only your team can decide if the approach is realistic.  "Any down-side to 7.7?" - You currently cannot upgrade to RHEL 8.1 if you are running RHEL 7.7. "Has anyone experienced issues migrating to RHEL 8?" - This type of question is out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound: `Any down-side to 7.7?" - You currently cannot upgrade to RHEL 8.1 if you are running RHEL 7.7`  That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottieH - That is well documented by Redhat, but the knowlegebase article requires a subscription, something proper research would have discovered.

Comment: @ScottieH - I wasn't saying it to be smug.  I was annoyed that RedHat put it behind a subscription.  I also deal with a closed offline isolated system, but that system has a subscription, it's just not accessible to me.  I incorrectly assumed you had a subscription.  I apologize.

Comment: Hey, I'm always down to dis the redhat subscription issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommand to not make an update to 7.7 because once done you will not be able to upgrade to rhel 8 during the next cycle because there is no support yet within **Leapp** utility to upgrade from 7.7 to 8, only 7.6 to 8 is supported for now.

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted? [How To Upgrade From RHEL 7 to RHEL 8](https://www.errorhat.com/how-to-upgrade-from-rhel-7-to-rhel-8/) it absolutely is correct.  The Redhat knowlegebase, that indicates this is the fact, is hidden behind a subscription.

Comment: @Ramhound I down voted. Same reason I am voting to close: This question is too broad without knowing exactly *what* is being developed and in *what* language. And the question is not about upgrading a server from 7 to 8 but rather software development in 7 versus 8. The vast majority of software development in 2020 is platform agnostic: PHP code “written” and run on Ubuntu can work on RedHat as long as the PHP version, modules and configs are fairly similar. All you get between OS and versions are what default packages are installed; stuff easily dealt with by adding non-official repos.

Comment: @JakeGould: It is exactly the answer I was looking for. I am on a closed network. I cannot use Non-Official repos. Once I choose a platform. I am "stuck with it" for 3 years. Please do NOT assume everyone has access to the internet all the time. It may seem easy & broad scoped to you. That is not so in my environment.

Comment: @ScottieH And — as I said previously — you haven’t stated what you are developing in. That matters. Additionally, “…no support yet within Leapp…” seems like a issue that will be solved within 2 to 3 years; I doubt RedHat would abandon 7.7 users who want to go to 8 as if somehow 7.7 was some cursed patch version.

Comment: Explain, please, why "what you are developing in" matters. I did not post it because I'm not sure I _CAN_ post it. What are you looking for? Java, C++, Fortran? That kind of thing?